# Custom Script for windows installer in Install4j

Tags: install4j

I want to run a custom script at the end of installation on windows platform. Something as below

```
icacls C:\InstallDir /remove "NT Authority\Authenticated Users" /t
```

We just want to remove non-privileged user from accessing the installation directory. Is there a way to add custom scripts in install4j to achieve the same. Any different suggestion will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a "Run executable or batch file" action to the "Installation" screen of your installer with the following properties:

"Executable" property: `${installer:sys.system32Dir}\icacls.exe`

"Arguments" property (one argument per line):

```
 ${installer:sys.installationDir}
 ${installer:sys.installationDir}
 /remove
```

"Wait for termination" property: Selected

"Redirect stdout" property: To log file

"Redirect stderr" property: To log file

"Condition expression" property: `Util.isWindows()`
NT Authority\Authenticated Users
/t